# PHP Arabic trim letter

Tags: php

i have  `$string="أحمد";`

when i add trim function  `echo trim("أحمد","أ");`

my output `�مد`

any one can help me ? and how to solve this problem while using search in php  by using Like in sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use string replace instead

`echo str_replace('أ', '', 'أحمد');`

Comment: true answer but can you help me how to use this condition in search from db

Comment: I can't understand what you want exactly
You can use this query `SELECT * FROM table WHERE field like '%احمد'`
this will catch احمد, محمد, أحمد, etc...